# Is it possible to print a number formatted with thousand separator in Rust?

Tags: rust

For instance

```
println!("{}", 10_000_000);
```

results in

```
10000000
```

whereas I'd like to format it to look something like

```
10,000,000
```

I went through [the `fmt` module documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/), but there's nothing to cover this particular situation. I thought something like this would work

```
println!("{:,i}", 10_000_000);
```

but it throws an error

```
invalid format string: expected `}`, found `,`
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible without writing custom code right now.

Comment: Why `10,000,000` and not `1,00,00,000`? How would you indicate how to group digits?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thousand separator for readability. Most if not all the languages have this functionality, so I was wondering if Rust does too.

Comment: @Caballero: the thing is, different cultures separate differently; the second format is how Indians do it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I didn't realize that there are different notations. I was referring to more or less SI standard - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The [num_format crate](https://crates.io/crates/num-format) will solve this issue for you. Add your locale and it will do the magic.

Answer (score 17):

*the simplest way to format a number with thousands separator – but w/o* Locale
use the `thousands` crate

```
use thousands::Separable;

println!("{}", 10_000_000.separate_with_commas());
```

---

*a one-liner*
using only the Rust std library

```
let num = 10_000_000.to_string()
    .as_bytes()
    .rchunks(3)
    .rev()
    .map(std::str::from_utf8)
    .collect::<Result<Vec<&str>, _>>()
    .unwrap()
    .join(",");  // separator
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2e4916721f625988d9a4f9a5cdb635ae) contains an enhanced solution that also formats negative numbers

Comment: The one-liner is much nicer than what i managed to write, but for -123 it returns  -,123.

Comment: @szabgab The solution was originally not intended for negative values. But it can be extended relatively easily for negative values: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2e4916721f625988d9a4f9a5cdb635ae)

Answer (score 5):

There isn't, and there probably won't be.

Depending on where you are, the thousands separator may also work like `1,00,00,000`, or `1.000.000,000` or some other variant.

Localization isn't the job of the stdlib, plus `format!` is mostly handled at compile time (though to be fair this could be placed in its runtime portion easily), and you don't want to hard-bake a locale into the program.

Comment: “Localization isn’t the job of the stdlib” is severely debatable. I certainly disagree with it, though I will say that it isn’t *yet* suitable to have it as part of the standard libraries.

Comment: That is assuming that your culture group digits by 3.

Comment: The number of digits per group and the separator could be specified. E.g. groups of 4 separated by _ would make a nice output format for binary or hexadecimal digits. (As far as I could find out Italian also uses groups of three digits, not the irregular format mentioned above.)

Comment: @starblue The "irregular format" is used in India and in other places in South Asia. It's not a niche thing.

Comment: Nonsense. There should be a format!() string which says "add this seperator every x digits" the same way we can tell format!() to add a decimal point and how many decimal places to show and how many zeroes to pad.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a naive implementation for integers

```rust
fn pretty_print_int(i: isize) {
    let mut s = String::new();
    let i_str = i.to_string();
    let a = i_str.chars().rev().enumerate();
    for (idx, val) in a {
        if idx != 0 && idx % 3 == 0 {
            s.insert(0, ',');
        }
        s.insert(0, val);
    }
    println!("{}", s);
}

pretty_print_int(10_000_000);
// 10,000,000
```

If you want to make this a little more generic for integers you could use the [num::Integer](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.40/num/trait.Integer.html) trait

```rust
extern crate num;

use num::Integer;

fn pretty_print_int<T: Integer>(i: T) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a custom function, I played around with this and here are some ideas:

```
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let i = 10_000_000i;
    println!("{}", decimal_mark1(i.to_string()));
    println!("{}", decimal_mark2(i.to_string()));
    println!("{}", decimal_mark3(i.to_string()));
}

fn decimal_mark1(s: String) -> String {
    let bytes: Vec<_> = s.bytes().rev().collect();
    let chunks: Vec<_> = bytes.chunks(3).map(|chunk| str::from_utf8(chunk).unwrap()).collect();
    let result: Vec<_> = chunks.join(" ").bytes().rev().collect();
    String::from_utf8(result).unwrap()
}

fn decimal_mark2(s: String) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(s.len() + ((s.len() - 1) / 3));
    let mut i = s.len();
    for c in s.chars() {
        result.push(c);
        i -= 1;
        if i > 0 && i % 3 == 0 {
            result.push(' ');
        }
    }
    result
}

fn decimal_mark3(s: String) -> String {
    let mut result = String::with_capacity(s.len() + ((s.len() - 1) / 3));
    let first = s.len() % 3;
    result.push_str(s.slice_to(first));
    for chunk in s.slice_from(first).as_bytes().chunks(3) {
        if !result.is_empty() {
            result.push(' ');
        }
        result.push_str(str::from_utf8(chunk).unwrap());
    }
    result
}
```

[Playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=a5f28af16861361b8377e202e5a6396e)

Comments welcome, none of them feels really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Another workaround for this is to use the [`separator` crate](https://github.com/saghm/rust-separator) which implements a `.separated_string()` method on float, integer and size types. Here is an example:

```
extern crate separator;
use separator::Separatable;

fn main() {
    let x1: u16 = 12345;
    let x2: u64 = 4242424242;
    let x3: u64 = 232323232323;
    println!("Unsigned ints:\n{:>20}\n{:>20}\n{:>20}\n", x1.separated_string(), x2.separated_string(), x3.separated_string());

    let x1: i16 = -12345;
    let x2: i64 = -4242424242;
    let x3: i64 = -232323232323;
    println!("Signed ints:\n{:>20}\n{:>20}\n{:>20}\n", x1.separated_string(), x2.separated_string(), x3.separated_string());


    let x1: f32 = -424242.4242;
    let x2: f64 = 23232323.2323;
    println!("Floats:\n{:>20}\n{:>20}\n", x1.separated_string(), x2.separated_string());


    let x1: usize = 424242;
    // let x2: isize = -2323232323;  // Even though the docs say so, the traits seem not to be implemented for isize
    println!("Size types:\n{:>20}\n", x1.separated_string());        
}
```

Which gives you the following output:

```
Unsigned ints:
              12,345
       4,242,424,242
     232,323,232,323

Signed ints:
             -12,345
      -4,242,424,242
    -232,323,232,323

Floats:
         -424,242.44
     23,232,323.2323

Size types:
             424,242
```

Note that aligning floats like this is not easy since `separated_string()` returns a string. However, this is a relatively quick way to get separated numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple to write code to do this manually. Here's some code which operates directly on strings to do it. This has the advantage of allowing you to use decimal place formatting using the normal methods (I don't think any of the existing options allow that). Also it avoids pulling in over-complicated dependencies for something so simple. Feel free to copy/paste (public domain):

```rust
/// Add thousands comma separators to a number. The number must match the following
/// regex: `^-?\d*(\.\d*)?$`. Returns None if it does not match that format.
/// Note that empty strings and just `-` are allowed.
pub fn with_comma_separators(s: &str) -> Option<String> {
    // Position of the `.`
    let dot = s.bytes().position(|c| c == b'.').unwrap_or(s.len());
    // Is the number negative (starts with `-`)?
    let negative = s.bytes().next() == Some(b'-');
    // The dot cannot be at the front if it is negative.
    assert!(!(negative && dot == 0));
    // Number of integer digits remaning (between the `-` or start and the `.`).
    let mut integer_digits_remaining = dot - negative as usize;
    // Output. Add capacity for commas. It's a slight over-estimate but that's fine.
    let mut out = String::with_capacity(s.len() + integer_digits_remaining / 3);

    // We can iterate on bytes because everything must be ASCII. Slightly faster.
    for (i, c) in s.bytes().enumerate() {
        match c {
            b'-' => {
                // `-` can only occur at the start of the string.
                if i != 0 {
                    return None;
                }
            }
            b'.' => {
                // Check we only have a dot at the expected position.
                // This return may happen if there are multiple dots.
                if i != dot {
                    return None;
                }
            }
            b'0'..=b'9' => {
                // Possibly add a comma.
                if integer_digits_remaining > 0 {
                    // Don't add a comma at the start of the string.
                    if i != negative as usize && integer_digits_remaining % 3 == 0 {
                        out.push(',');
                    }
                    integer_digits_remaining -= 1;
                }
            }
            _ => {
                // No other characters allowed.
                return None;
            }
        }
        out.push(c as char);
    }
    Some(out)
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod test {
    use super::with_comma_separators;

    #[test]
    fn basic() {
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("123.45").as_deref(), Some("123.45"));
        assert_eq!(
            with_comma_separators("1234.56").as_deref(),
            Some("1,234.56")
        );
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators(".56").as_deref(), Some(".56"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("56").as_deref(), Some("56"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("567").as_deref(), Some("567"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("5678").as_deref(), Some("5,678"));
        assert_eq!(
            with_comma_separators("12345678").as_deref(),
            Some("12,345,678")
        );
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("5678.").as_deref(), Some("5,678."));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators(".0123").as_deref(), Some(".0123"));

        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-123.45").as_deref(), Some("-123.45"));
        assert_eq!(
            with_comma_separators("-1234.56").as_deref(),
            Some("-1,234.56")
        );
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-.56").as_deref(), Some("-.56"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-56").as_deref(), Some("-56"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-567").as_deref(), Some("-567"));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-5678").as_deref(), Some("-5,678"));
        assert_eq!(
            with_comma_separators("-12345678").as_deref(),
            Some("-12,345,678")
        );
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-5678.").as_deref(), Some("-5,678."));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-.0123").as_deref(), Some("-.0123"));

        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("").as_deref(), Some(""));
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("-").as_deref(), Some("-"));

        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("a").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("0-").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("0..1").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("0..1").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("01a").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators("01.a").as_deref(), None);
        assert_eq!(with_comma_separators(".0.").as_deref(), None);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using this function with modifications. See the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72888582/choose-thousands-and-decimal-separators-for-f64-in-rust). Good results.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't immediately need Strings, and perhaps need variable grouping, you might want to consider an iterator-based approach.

```rust
fn thsep(digits: &str, n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &str> {
    let (chars, tip) = (digits.as_bytes(), digits.len() % n);
    if tip != 0 { Some(&chars[..tip]) } else { None }
        .into_iter()
        .chain(chars[tip..].chunks(n))
        .map(|digits| {
            std::str::from_utf8(digits).expect("unexpected non-utf8 char encountered")
        })
}

fn join(i: impl Iterator<Item = &'static str>) -> String {
    i.collect::<Vec<_>>().join(",")
}

fn main() {
    let val = "1234567890";
    println!("{}", join(thsep(val, 1))); // 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0
    println!("{}", join(thsep(val, 2))); // 12,34,56,78,90
    println!("{}", join(thsep(val, 3))); // 1,234,567,890 • 3
    println!("{}", join(thsep(val, 4))); // 12,3456,7890
}
```