# Human readable numbers

Tags: rust, human-readable

Is there an easy way and dynamic way to format numbers in a string to be human readable? For example turn `10000000000` into `10,000,000,000`. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998485/rust-print-format-number-with-thousand-separator) question but the answers are outdated and broken (the one with the example).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998485/rust-print-format-number-with-thousand-separator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my locale this seemed to work! Probably isn't the most idiomatic rust, but it is functional.

```
fn readable(mut o_s: String) -> String {
    let mut s = String::new();
    let mut negative = false;
    let values: Vec<char> = o_s.chars().collect();
    if values[0] == '-' {
        o_s.remove(0);
        negative = true;
    }
    for (i ,char) in o_s.chars().rev().enumerate() {
        if i % 3 == 0 && i != 0 {
            s.insert(0, ',');
        }
        s.insert(0, char);
    }
    if negative {
        s.insert(0, '-');
    }
    return s
}

fn main() {
    let value: i64 = -100000000000;
    let new_value = readable(value.to_string());
    println!("{}", new_value);
}
```

Comment: This wont work for some negative numbers, try "-100000000" for example.

Comment: @DylanJamesMcGannon Thanks for pointing that out. I have resolved that issue.

Answer (score 5):

Try this psuedo algorithm:

1. Divide the string length by 3
2. Round that down, and we'll call it `x`
3. Loop over the string `x` times, going backwards:

   1. Get the string at `x` times 3 position, or index [(x times 3) - 1], we'll call it `y`.
   2. Replace `y` with `"," + y`

Answer (score 3):

I've never used rust in my life but this is what I came up with by translating a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1449859/5760823):

```
fn main() {
    let i = -117608854;
    printcomma(i);
}

fn printcomma(mut i: i32) {
    if i < 0 {
        print!("-");
        i=-i;
    }
    if i < 1000 {
        print!("{}", i.to_string());
        return;
    }
    printcomma(i/1000);
    print!(",{:03}", i%1000);
}
```

returns "-117,608,854"