# How can I change the formatter's decimal separator in Rust?

Tags: localization, rust

The function below results in "10.000". Where I live this means "ten thousand".

```
format!("{:.3}", 10.0);
```

I would like the output to be "10,000".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rust: print/format number with thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998485/rust-print-format-number-with-thousand-separator)

Comment: @ljedrz No, the OP clearly ask for floating number. Your question is about integer.

Comment: The answer to that question covers floats too, but you're right; this question is not exactly a duplicate.

Comment: cf. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19752#issuecomment-66684082

Comment: @Stargateur: When evaluating duplicates, answers count as much as questions. In this case however, I would not mark it as duplicate, as one is talking about thousand separators (nigh exclusively) without any code sample and the other about decimal separators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the standard library doesn't have this functionality (localization of number format), you can just replace the dot with a comma:

```
fn main() {
    println!("{}", format!("{:.3}", 10.0).replacen(".", ",", 1));
}
```

There are other ways of doing this, but this is probably the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I hate this solution, but I guess I have no choice at the moment :-)

Comment: I first forgot that it existed and attempted to implement it myself and believe me - this one is actually pretty pleasant ;).

Comment: For proper i18n support, see https://crates.io/crates/num-format and https://crates.io/crates/gettext

Comment: If you don't want to use gettext because of the LGPL license, try https://mozilla-l10n.github.io/localizer-documentation/tools/fluent/basic_syntax.html#selectors-and-plurals instead

Answer (score 9):

There is no support for internationalization (i18n) or localization (l10n) baked in the Rust standard library.

---

There are several reasons, in no particular order:

1. a locale-dependent output should be a conscious choice, not a default,
2. i18n and l10n are much more complicated than just formatting numbers,
3. the Rust std aims at being small.

The `format!` machinery is going to be used to write JSON or XML files. You really do NOT want to end up with a differently formatted file depending on the locale of the machine that encoded it. It's a recipe for disaster.

The detection of locale at run-time is also optimization unfriendly. Suddenly you cannot pre-compute things at compile-time (even partially), you cannot even know which size of buffer to allocate at compile-time.

And this ties in with a dubious usefulness. Dates and numbers are arguably important, however this American vs English formatting war is ultimately a drop in the ocean. A French grammar schooler will certainly appreciate that the number is formatted in the typical French format... but it will be of no avail to her if the surrounding text is in English (we French are notoriously bad at teaching/learning foreign languages). Locale should influence language selection, sorting order, etc... merely changing the format of numbers is pointless, *everything* should switch with it, and this requires much more serious support (check `gettext` for a C library that provides a good *base*).

Basing the detection of the locale on the host locale, and it being global to the whole process, is also a *very* dubious architectural choice in this age of multi-threaded web servers. Imagine if Facebook was served in Swedish in Europe just because its datacenter is running there.

Finally, all this language/date/... support requires a humongous amount of data. [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) has several dozens (or is it hundreds?) of MBs of such data embedded inside it. This would make the size of the `std` explode, and make it completely unsuitable for embedded development; which probably do not care about this anyway.

Of course, you could cut down on this significantly if you only chose to support a handful of languages... which is yet another argument for putting this outside the standard library.

Comment: Sure, but OP does not speak about `std`: there could be some official extern crate for internationalization, baked by the rust team. You are right IMO about *not* putting this stuff in `std`, but to develop in a modern language, this must exist somewhere.

Comment: @Boiethios: I hear you... but the SO format just doesn't lend itself well to recommending libraries unfortunately. Most notably because of inertia in the answers which means that 2 years from now the top answer may refer to a dead library (which is the reason questions asking for such references are closed, btw). Thus I prefer to limit myself to the explanation of why the standard library doesn't provide it; and this frees the OP to shop around rather than try and wait for the std solution (search for "locale" on crates.io, ask questions on IRC/Reddit/the users forum/...).

Comment: Mmh you are right. I will think about that when I answer something.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a usable crate for this at the moment? (I understand why you don't mention it in your answer, but maybe a comment is ok)

Comment: @r03: Stargateur suggested one, I have no idea how good or bad it is. If this is important to you, I really advise searching/asking the community (not on SO) about it.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the role of the macro `format!`. This option should be handle by Rust. Unfortunately, my search lead me to the conclusion that Rust don't handle locale (yet ?).

There is a library [rust-locale](https://github.com/rust-locale/rust-locale/), but they are still in alpha.