# How do I print an integer in binary with leading zeros?

Tags: rust

I'm doing some bit twiddling and I'd like to print all the bits in my u16.

```
let flags = 0b0000000000101100u16;
println!("flags: {:#b}", flags);
```

This prints `flags: 0b101100`.

How do I make it print `flags: 0b0000000000101100`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have come to prefer these patterns:

```
println!("{:08b}", 1i8);
println!("{:016b}", 12000u16);
println!("{:032b}", 624485u32);
```

it will print:

```
00000001
0010111011100000
00000000000010011000011101100101
```

Answer (score 75):

```
let flags = 0b0000000000101100u16;
println!("flags: {:#018b}", flags);
```

The `018` pads with zeros to a width of 18. That width includes `0b` (length=2) plus a u16 (length=16) so `18 = 2 + 16`. It must come **between** `#` and `b`.

Rust's fmt docs explain both [leading zeros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0) and [radix formatting](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#formatting-traits), but don't show how to combine them.

Here are u8, u16, and u32:

```
//                       Width  0       8      16      24      32
//                              |       |       |       |       |
println!("{:#010b}", 1i8);  // 0b00000001
println!("{:#018b}", 1i16); // 0b0000000000000001
println!("{:#034b}", 1i32); // 0b00000000000000000000000000000001
```

Comment: How can I put underscores in between to make it more readable?

Comment: @AtulGopinathan you will need a custom crate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998485/is-it-possible-to-print-a-number-formatted-with-thousand-separator-in-rust

Comment: How about using `0b{:08b}` instead of `{:#010b}`? It's easier to reason `8` than `10`.

Comment: @AtulGopinathan A crate for this is convenient, but not necessary; instead of `println!("{:08b}", my_u8_value)`, try `println!("{:04b}_{:04b}", my_u8_value >> 4, my_u8_value & 0x0f)`