# How to format a byte into a 2 digit hex string, in Rust

Tags: rust, string-formatting

Commonly one wants to print a byte as 2 hex digits, for example `10` should give `0x0a`. In Rust one would use something like `println!("{:#02x}", 10)`, but it gives `0xa`.

A list of things I've tried (using info from [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/index.html) and [`fmt::LowerHex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.LowerHex.html) and several StackOverflow  questions):

```rust
println!("{:#02x}", 10);
println!("{:#0x}", 10);
println!("{:#x}", 10);
println!("{:#x?}", 10);
println!("{:#0x?}", 10);
println!("{:#02x?}", 10);
```

All of them output `0xa`, instead of the desired behavior of `0x0A`.

---

This question has been edited (removing relevant emotion), and subsequently marked as a duplicate of other questions. But other answers do not address why the list above doesn't work. The `#` format option results in unexpected output (`0xa`), and in particular the `02`, surprisingly, has *no effect at all!* No other question focusses on this, nor on `#` in particular.

Comment: *But other answers do not address why the list above doesn't work* — sure they do: [*The 018 pads with zeros to a width of 18. That width includes 0b (length=2) plus a u16 (length=16) so 18 = 2 + 16*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44690529/155423)

Comment: 1) link 1 doesn't discuss the 2-character width requirement, and as many others do not discuss values below 16. 2) link 2 explains the mechanisms of the `#` option well, but doesn't address the dumb-founding specific case that occurs when rendering bytes (and which the compiler fails to flag). 3) The byte case is most common and yet is ignored even in the LowerHex docs. 4) No answer (anywhere) addresses that `#` has fundamental problems, so {:#04x} is erroneously recommended as a general solution. 5) No teaching of `0x{:02x}`, which would avoid the question from arising again.

Answer (score 43):

As documented in the [`std::fmt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0) module:

> `#` - This flag is indicates that the "alternate" form of printing should be used. The alternate forms are:
>
> - `#x` - precedes the argument with a 0x
> - `#X` - precedes the argument with a 0x

This interacts with the request width, because the width accounts for the *whole* substitution and thus `0x0a` is **4** characters, not 2.

If you request a width that is less than the necessary width, the requested width is disregarded and the minimum width is used instead (here 3 characters).

A quick experiment [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fae66e4c050d1a343aa99881d91d2aad):

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:#01x}", 10);
    println!("{:#02x}", 10);
    println!("{:#03x}", 10);
    println!("{:#04x}", 10);
    println!("{:#05x}", 10);
    println!("{:#06x}", 10);
}
```

Prints:

```
0xa
0xa
0xa
0x0a
0x00a
0x000a
```

All is well.

Answer (score 18):

If you use:

```
println!("10 is 0x{:02x} in hex", 10);       // ==> "0x0a"
```

Instead of:

```
println!("10 is {:#02x} in hex", 10);        //     "0xa"
```

It works.

However, as the commenters pointed out this is no bug, but confusion about the meaning of `02`. It does not mean the minimal number of *significant* digits, but the minimum total number of characters, which now must include `0x`. So this works also:

```
println!("10 is {:#04x} in hex", 10);        //     "0x0a"
```

But there are problems with this solution and the culture that promotes this as the "correct" solution.

First note that the inclusion of `0x` through `#` promotes the concept of total width, which the `04` now specifies. One needs to mentally subtract 2 to get to the significant digits, which is the significant part. Regardless `{:#04x}` will format 10000 as `0x2710`, which occupies 6 characters, not 4. So the concept of total width fails, as a concept, perhaps too trivially so.

In addition `{:#03x}`, `{:#02x}` and `{:#01x}` confusingly all result in the same behaviour as `{:#x}, and are not flagged by the compiler (1.35) though they make no sense and indicate an error.

Secondly, the `#` formatter is only useful for Rust-specific number representations, inserting for example `0x` but not `$` (another common hex representation format).

Thirly, crucially, the concept of total width only becomes explicit when the `#` formatter is used (and then silently fails in the common byte case). The `#` formatter means Rust has *the option* to consider the total width, and one should use it when it applies (that is in the context of fixed-width layouts).

The remainder shows why `#` is a special case solution, and why it is not recommended in the general case.

A formatter string should be chosen depending on the context, specifically how one thinks about displaying a number in that context, as the chosen format expresses intent. So:

- `{:#04x}` focuses on the total width, useful when doing a rigid fixed-width table layout. The `#` formatter clearly is ergonomic in this case. `{:#04x}` is also obviously useful when generating a custom formatting string (given a fixed-width context), for example when the output needs to be changed from hex to binary on demand (e.g. `{:#04x}` to `{:#04b}`), though it is hard to imagine concrete cases.
- `0x{02x}` expresses the number of significant digits, useful when the main concern is how to represent information on a line, given limited space. A common edit in this case is to remove the `0x`. With `0x{:02x}` the `0x` is simply removed, whereas with the `{:#04}` formatter one would need to remove both the `#` and substitute the `04` for `02`. The end result is the same in both cases: `{:02x}`, but `#` required a concept shift.

Depending on the case the `#` formatter is ergonomic and expressive of intent, or it is not. Use the format that meshes with what you want to achieve. But in the general case it is probably best to regard `#` as a relatively obscure feature. Its additional smartness is only desirable in well-defined cases.

Unfortunately other answers suggest `{:#04x}` as the default, "correct" or the "Rust solution". However, the fact a certain feature (`#`) is available doesn't mean that:
- Rust endorses it, or it is otherwise recommended to use it, 
- the underlying concept of total width needs expressing, or
- the concept of total width should generalize to all of Rust format expressions (which is the root problem most answers demonstrate)

In summary *Rust made `#` available, but `0x{:02x}` is still often simpler, more to the point and universally recognized. It is [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) and doesn't have hidden defects*.

Comment: Just `println!("{:#04x}", 10);` - -

Comment: How do you know that it is a long-standing bug? Do you have an issue at the github repo?

Comment: The `#` flag *should* make a difference, because it's telling it to use the alternate form (`0x` prefix for hex numbers). Not a bug. https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/#sign0