# Rust: Create array from function at compilation

Tags: rust

I am looking for a solution to translate the following c++ function to Rust

```cpp
    uint32_t reverseBits(uint32_t n) {
        static constexpr array<uint8_t, 256> table{[]() constexpr{
                constexpr size_t SIZE = 256;
                array<uint8_t, SIZE> result{};

                for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
                    result[i] = (i * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 0x3ff;
                return result;
        }()};
```

However:

- I cannot use `#![feature(const_fn)]` because `#![feature] may not be used on the stable release channel`.
- I cannot use build.rs and cargo either
- I thought about using macro_rules! but I cannot find a very simple example to precompute in a loop like:

```cpp
for (size_t i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i)
   result[i] = (i * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 0x3ff; // reverse bits
```

NB: My attemp to translate the full c++ code to Rust, with the table unfortunately computed at runtime:

```
    pub fn reverse_bits(x: u32) -> u32 {
        let table: [u32; 256];

        for i in 0..10 {
            table[i] = ((i as u64 * 0x0202020202 as u64 & 0x010884422010 as u64) % 0x3ff) as u32;
        }

        return (table[x & 0xff] << 24) | (table[(x >> 8) & 0xff] << 16) |
            (table[(x >> 16) & 0xff] << 8) | (table[(x >> 24) & 0xff]);
    }
```

also running into `the type[u32] cannot be indexed by u32`...

I anyone knows how I could build an array, at compile time, with 256 u32 values where each values is equal to `(index * 0x0202020202ULL & 0x010884422010ULL) % 0x3ff;` it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot use `#![feature(const_fn)]` because `#![feature]` may not be used on the stable release channel.

Well, I have good news for you: `const fn` has been part of stable Rust for quite a while now, so you can use it. But it will require some adjustments to the code.

First, you need to fix the issues that have nothing to do with `const`. As the error message tells you, you need to cast to `usize` to index an array. Your array should be initialized to 0 (which the C++ code actually does), and should be `mut`.

Then, to make it `const fn`, you need to replace the `for` loop (which is not yet allowed in `const fn`) with tail recursion, i.e. change:

```
for i in 0..10 {
    table[i] = ...;
}
```

to something like:

```
const fn set_table(mut table: [u32; 256], i: usize) -> [u32; 256] {
    if i == 10 {
        return table;
    }
    table[i] = ...;
    return set_table(table, i + 1);
}
table = set_table(table, 0);
```

Note that we have to pass the ownership of the table to the tail-recursive function and get it back from it because mutable references are not supported in `const fn`.

Finally, the C++ code uses a nice constant for `SIZE`, which we can do in Rust as well. The final result looks like this and builds using stable Rust on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=954930d4a5ff3894db0c455ede283d10):

```
pub const fn reverse_bits(x: u32) -> u32 {
    const SIZE: usize = 256;
    let mut table = [0u32; SIZE];

    const fn set_table(mut table: [u32; SIZE], i: usize) -> [u32; SIZE] {
        if i == SIZE {
            return table;
        }
        table[i] = ((i as u64 * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 0x3ff) as u32;
        return set_table(table, i + 1);
    }
    table = set_table(table, 0);

    return (table[(x & 0xff) as usize] << 24)
        | (table[((x >> 8) & 0xff) as usize] << 16)
        | (table[((x >> 16) & 0xff) as usize] << 8)
        | (table[((x >> 24) & 0xff) as usize]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user4815162342, really appreciate your help however it does not compile: `if i == SIZE` --> `loops and conditional expressions are not stable in const fn`, and compiler recommending to use !feature(const_fn)

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL Have you checked the [playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=954930d4a5ff3894db0c455ede283d10), where I tested it to compile on stable? Perhaps you are using an older version of Rust?

Comment: I am compiling from https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-bits/

Comment: Leetcode uses Rust 1.40 apparently. They're a bit out of date.

Comment: also, very minor question, but when I want to get the string display the number with bits reverse, the MSB is skipped, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81b27e4a34cd5f33d7a3772670d9fd25 any solution for this?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL In that case I'm afraid I cannot help you more than I did. While the `const fn` support is quite mature now, the site is using the compiler version released in 2019 (!), so it just doesn't allow this to be implemented at compile time.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL I haven't tried to test the function, I just took the code you provided. You can drop the `const` and debug it by using prints or a debugger.

Comment: If it is because of an out of date compiler I will select it as answer. I think my (sad) solution, will be to print the resulting array locally and copy paste the values... Thanks a lot anyways!

Comment: BTW, https://blog.rust-lang.org/2021/02/26/const-generics-mvp-beta.html, I didn't read the full thread so I don"t know if it's could help

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not 100% sure, but I *think* const generics don't really help here. I was pleasantly surprised that Rust allowed the inner function `set_table` to accept and return `[u32; SIZE]` with `SIZE` being a constant defined inside the outer function. (Rust is otherwise quite picky about inner function signature; for example it doesn't allow the inner function to refer to a generic type defined in the outer function's signature; the inner function must re-declare the generic and supply it at the call site.) If not for that, const generics would surely be needed for `set_table`.

Answer (score 1):

## A macro you should not use

> I thought about using macro_rules! but I cannot find a very simple example to precompute in a loop

You can't just loop from 0 to 256 in a declarative macro because macros only know about the presence or absence of tokens, not their values. But there are other ways to approach these kinds of problems. Here's a macro that generates an array literal suitable for assignment to `[u32; 256]`:

```
macro_rules! table {
    () => { table!(@ (do re mi fa sol la ti do) 0u64) };
    (@ ($_:tt $($bin:tt)*) $($etc:expr),*) => {
        table!(@ ($($bin)*) $($etc*2, $etc*2 + 1),*)
    };
    (@ () $($i:expr),*) => {
        [$((($i * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 0x3ff) as u32),*]
    };
}
```

This macro works in stages. When called without arguments (the first branch), it calls itself (the second branch) with a parenthesized sequence of 8 tokens and an increasing integer sequence initially containing just the one value `0u64`. (The parenthesized tokens don't matter, as long as there are exactly 8 of them.) It recursively calls itself (still in the second branch) for each token in the list, doubling the length of the integer sequence with each token consumed. After 8 doublings (2<sup>8</sup> = 256), the parentheses are empty and when it calls itself again (the third branch), it wraps each integer `$i` in `(($i * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 0x3ff) as u32` and puts the whole thing between square brackets.

[Here it is on the Rust Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12907c3c2d8cecab7a8671177b2cae02) You can check the generated code by expanding macros. It's... surprisingly not that hard to understand, if you recognize the binary encoding of the integers. But I would recommend against using it in real code, because it is non-obvious. Use `const` evaluation instead when you can.

## A more realistic macro-based answer

Generate the trivial, easy-to-verify part with your editor or preferred scripting language and use the macro for the repetitive part.

```
macro_rules! table {
    ($($i:expr,)*) => {
        [$((($i as u64 * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 0x3ff) as u32),*]
    };
}
const TABLE: [u32; 256] = table![
    0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
    0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e, 0x2f,
    0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39, 0x3a, 0x3b, 0x3c, 0x3d, 0x3e, 0x3f,
    0x40, 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x4f,
    0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5a, 0x5b, 0x5c, 0x5d, 0x5e, 0x5f,
    0x60, 0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x6d, 0x6e, 0x6f,
    0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x7b, 0x7c, 0x7d, 0x7e, 0x7f,
    0x80, 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x84, 0x85, 0x86, 0x87, 0x88, 0x89, 0x8a, 0x8b, 0x8c, 0x8d, 0x8e, 0x8f,
    0x90, 0x91, 0x92, 0x93, 0x94, 0x95, 0x96, 0x97, 0x98, 0x99, 0x9a, 0x9b, 0x9c, 0x9d, 0x9e, 0x9f,
    0xa0, 0xa1, 0xa2, 0xa3, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0xa6, 0xa7, 0xa8, 0xa9, 0xaa, 0xab, 0xac, 0xad, 0xae, 0xaf,
    0xb0, 0xb1, 0xb2, 0xb3, 0xb4, 0xb5, 0xb6, 0xb7, 0xb8, 0xb9, 0xba, 0xbb, 0xbc, 0xbd, 0xbe, 0xbf,
    0xc0, 0xc1, 0xc2, 0xc3, 0xc4, 0xc5, 0xc6, 0xc7, 0xc8, 0xc9, 0xca, 0xcb, 0xcc, 0xcd, 0xce, 0xcf,
    0xd0, 0xd1, 0xd2, 0xd3, 0xd4, 0xd5, 0xd6, 0xd7, 0xd8, 0xd9, 0xda, 0xdb, 0xdc, 0xdd, 0xde, 0xdf,
    0xe0, 0xe1, 0xe2, 0xe3, 0xe4, 0xe5, 0xe6, 0xe7, 0xe8, 0xe9, 0xea, 0xeb, 0xec, 0xed, 0xee, 0xef,
    0xf0, 0xf1, 0xf2, 0xf3, 0xf4, 0xf5, 0xf6, 0xf7, 0xf8, 0xf9, 0xfa, 0xfb, 0xfc, 0xfd, 0xfe, 0xff,
];
```

Comment: very nice, it still doesnt work on leetcode but appreciate your effort. Also do not use such click bait title, you know that when something is forbidden you create more attraction ;)

Comment: Hm. I tested it with Rust 1.40 in [Compiler Explorer and it seems fine](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/364ovP). Maybe leetcode isn't using that version after all? The same strategy should work all the way back to 1.2.0 if you replace `$_` with `$_b` (not sure when that change was made)

Answer (score 1):

### For leetcode only (old compiler from 2019...)

I had to do it in two steps:

#### Generate the output locally

```rs
const SIZE: usize = 256;

const fn set_table(mut table: [u32; SIZE], i: usize) -> [u32; SIZE] {
        if i == SIZE {
            return table;
        }
        table[i] = ((i as u64 * 0x0202020202 & 0x010884422010) % 0x3ff) as u32;
        return set_table(table, i + 1);
    }


fn main() {
    let mut table = [0u32; SIZE];
    table = set_table(table, 0);

    for x in 0..table.len() {
         print!("{:#x}, ", table[x]);
         if x % 16 == 15 {
            println!("");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Copy paste the raw value of the output to build my array

```rs
impl Solution {
    pub const fn reverse_bits(x: u32) -> u32 {
    const table: [u32; 256] = [0x0, 0x80, 0x40, 0xc0, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x60, 0xe0, 0x10, 0x90, 0x50, 0xd0, 0x30, 0xb0, 0x70, 0xf0, 
0x8, 0x88, 0x48, 0xc8, 0x28, 0xa8, 0x68, 0xe8, 0x18, 0x98, 0x58, 0xd8, 0x38, 0xb8, 0x78, 0xf8, 
0x4, 0x84, 0x44, 0xc4, 0x24, 0xa4, 0x64, 0xe4, 0x14, 0x94, 0x54, 0xd4, 0x34, 0xb4, 0x74, 0xf4, 
0xc, 0x8c, 0x4c, 0xcc, 0x2c, 0xac, 0x6c, 0xec, 0x1c, 0x9c, 0x5c, 0xdc, 0x3c, 0xbc, 0x7c, 0xfc, 
0x2, 0x82, 0x42, 0xc2, 0x22, 0xa2, 0x62, 0xe2, 0x12, 0x92, 0x52, 0xd2, 0x32, 0xb2, 0x72, 0xf2, 
0xa, 0x8a, 0x4a, 0xca, 0x2a, 0xaa, 0x6a, 0xea, 0x1a, 0x9a, 0x5a, 0xda, 0x3a, 0xba, 0x7a, 0xfa, 
0x6, 0x86, 0x46, 0xc6, 0x26, 0xa6, 0x66, 0xe6, 0x16, 0x96, 0x56, 0xd6, 0x36, 0xb6, 0x76, 0xf6, 
0xe, 0x8e, 0x4e, 0xce, 0x2e, 0xae, 0x6e, 0xee, 0x1e, 0x9e, 0x5e, 0xde, 0x3e, 0xbe, 0x7e, 0xfe, 
0x1, 0x81, 0x41, 0xc1, 0x21, 0xa1, 0x61, 0xe1, 0x11, 0x91, 0x51, 0xd1, 0x31, 0xb1, 0x71, 0xf1, 
0x9, 0x89, 0x49, 0xc9, 0x29, 0xa9, 0x69, 0xe9, 0x19, 0x99, 0x59, 0xd9, 0x39, 0xb9, 0x79, 0xf9, 
0x5, 0x85, 0x45, 0xc5, 0x25, 0xa5, 0x65, 0xe5, 0x15, 0x95, 0x55, 0xd5, 0x35, 0xb5, 0x75, 0xf5, 
0xd, 0x8d, 0x4d, 0xcd, 0x2d, 0xad, 0x6d, 0xed, 0x1d, 0x9d, 0x5d, 0xdd, 0x3d, 0xbd, 0x7d, 0xfd, 
0x3, 0x83, 0x43, 0xc3, 0x23, 0xa3, 0x63, 0xe3, 0x13, 0x93, 0x53, 0xd3, 0x33, 0xb3, 0x73, 0xf3, 
0xb, 0x8b, 0x4b, 0xcb, 0x2b, 0xab, 0x6b, 0xeb, 0x1b, 0x9b, 0x5b, 0xdb, 0x3b, 0xbb, 0x7b, 0xfb, 
0x7, 0x87, 0x47, 0xc7, 0x27, 0xa7, 0x67, 0xe7, 0x17, 0x97, 0x57, 0xd7, 0x37, 0xb7, 0x77, 0xf7, 
0xf, 0x8f, 0x4f, 0xcf, 0x2f, 0xaf, 0x6f, 0xef, 0x1f, 0x9f, 0x5f, 0xdf, 0x3f, 0xbf, 0x7f, 0xff];

    return (table[(x & 0xff) as usize] << 24)
        | (table[((x >> 8) & 0xff) as usize] << 16)
        | (table[((x >> 16) & 0xff) as usize] << 8)
        | (table[((x >> 24) & 0xff) as usize]);
    }
}
```

Obviously @trentcl and @user4815162342 methods are much better... if the compiler allows it.

NB: To check the result I used the following (thanks to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44690439/how-do-i-print-an-integer-in-binary-with-leading-zeros)):

```rs
let n:u32 = 43;
println!("{:#034b}", n);
let res:u32 = reverse_bits(n);
println!("{:#034b}", res);
```

Comment: If you generate the output locally, then you no longer need the function to be `const fn` and can ditch the tail recursion. In other words, you can just write `for i in 0..SIZE { table[i] = ... }` directly in `main()`.

Comment: I agree with your comment (the general idea) but on algorithm platforms the goals - one of, along with memory - is to have the lowest runtime that is why I get my array locally and then I copy-paste it on the algorithm platform. Anyways many thanks for your answer :) I really like it!