# Iterator-based code vs procedural code: how to make the iterator-based algorithm faster?

Tags: rust, iterator, benchmarking

I can see a huge difference in terms of performance, between an iterator-based algorithm (slow) and a procedural algorithm (fast). I want to improve the speed of the iterator-based algorithm but I don't know how to do it.

#### Context

I need to convert strings like `12345678` to `12_345_678`. Questions like this have already been asked like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998485/is-it-possible-to-print-a-number-formatted-with-thousand-separator-in-rust). (Note: I don't want to use a crate for this, because I have some custom needs about it).

*Edit*: it is assumed that the input string is ASCII.

I wrote two versions of the algorithm:

- an iterator-based version, but I'm not satisfied because there is two `.collect()`, which means many allocations (at least one `.collect()` is extra, without being able to remove it, see the code below);
- a procedural version of it.

Then I compared the execution time of the two versions: my iterator version is about *~8x slower* compared to the procedural version.

#### Benchmark code

```
use itertools::Itertools; // Using itertools v0.10.0

/// Size of the string blocks to separate:
const BLOCK_SIZE: usize = 3;

/// Procedural version.
fn procedural(input: &str) -> String {
    let len = input.len();
    let nb_complete_blocks = (len as isize - 1).max(0) as usize / BLOCK_SIZE;
    let first_block_len = len - nb_complete_blocks * BLOCK_SIZE;

    let capacity = first_block_len + nb_complete_blocks * (BLOCK_SIZE + 1);
    let mut output = String::with_capacity(capacity);

    output.push_str(&input[..first_block_len]);

    for i in 0..nb_complete_blocks {
        output.push('_');
        let start = first_block_len + i * BLOCK_SIZE;
        output.push_str(&input[start..start + BLOCK_SIZE]);
    }

    output
}

/// Iterator version.
fn with_iterators(input: &str) -> String {
    input.chars()
        .rev()
        .chunks(BLOCK_SIZE)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|c| c.collect::<String>())
        .join("_")
        .chars()
        .rev()
        .collect::<String>()
}

fn main() {
    let input = "12345678";

    macro_rules! bench {
        ( $version:ident ) => {{
            let now = std::time::Instant::now();
            for _ in 0..1_000_000 {
                $version(input);
            }
            println!("{:.2?}", now.elapsed());
        }};
    }

    print!("Procedural benchmark: ");
    bench!(procedural);

    print!("Iterator benchmark: ");
    bench!(with_iterators);
}
```

#### Typical benchmark result

```
Procedural benchmark: 17.07ms
Iterator benchmark: 240.19ms
```

#### Question

How can I improve the iterator-based version, in order to reach the performance of the procedural version ?

Comment: Did you run with `--release`?

Comment: @trentcl: no, I edited the benchmark with this option

Comment: Thanks for updating the figures! Even though in this case there's still a big difference, running with optimizations turned on is important for accurate benchmarks.

Answer (score 3):

The `with_iterators` version allocates a new `String` for every chunk in the `input` whereas the `procedural` version just slices the `input` and appends it to the `output` as necessary. Afterwards, these `String`s are joined into a reversed version of the target `String` which again has to be reversed into yet another `String`, including determining its char offsets and collecting into another `String`. This is a lot of additional work and would explain the massive slowdown.

You can do something very similar which will even be more robust than the `procedural` version through `chars` and `for_each`:

```
/// Iterator version.
fn with_iterators(input: &str) -> String {
    let n_chars = input.chars().count();
    let capacity = n_chars + n_chars / BLOCK_SIZE;
    let mut acc = String::with_capacity(capacity);
    input
        .chars()
        .enumerate()
        .for_each(|(idx, c)| {
            if idx != 0 && (n_chars - idx) % BLOCK_SIZE == 0 {
                acc.push('_');
            } 
            acc.push(c);
        });
    acc
}
```

Just slicing into a `&str` is prone to panics if you can't rule out that multi-byte encoded characters are part of the `input`. I.e., `procedural` assumes a 1-to-1 mapping between `u8` and `char` which is not given.

`chars` returns each character, with `enumerate()` you can track its offset in terms of other characters into the `str` and determine when to push the `'_'`.

The proposed version and the `procedural` version both run between 10-20ms on my machine.

Comment: This is far, far better thank you! Sorry, I forgot to say that `[u8]` was assumed, even if I prefer your logic. However if you consider utf-8 strings, there is a small error in your proposal: `(input.len() - idx)` should be `(nb_utf8_chars - idx)`, which could be calculated at the top of the function, with the right libs

Comment: Another slight improvement would be to calculate the input length at the top of the function, eg: `let len = input.len();`

Comment: Good points, I'll edit my answer tomorrow!

Comment: This would look very similar with just a simple `for` loop instead of using `.fold()`, and it might be a shade faster. Seems like we're trading "elegance" for performance.

Comment: Do you have a bench to support your claim that external iteration beats the internal iteration as by `fold()`?

Comment: Yes. I'll include it in my post.

Comment: Interesting, `fold()` seems to slow things down quite a bit, with `for_each()` it's on par with the explicit for loop in some criterion bench.

Comment: The `.for_each()` implementation is actually a little faster than your same function with a `for` loop on my system.

Comment: BTW, `.len()` and `.with_capacity()` respectively return and take the number of bytes. If we're assuming the strings are only ascii compatible utf-8, we can treat them as either char or byte for things like getting the char count - doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

This is also *very* slow. But here's a slightly different way for what it's worth.

```
fn iterators_todd(input: &str) -> String {
    let len     = input.len();
    let n_first = len % BLOCK_SIZE;
    let it      = input.chars();
    let mut out = it.clone().take(n_first).collect::<String>();

    if len > BLOCK_SIZE && n_first != 0 {
        out.push('_'); 
    }
    out.push_str(&it.skip(n_first)
                    .chunks(BLOCK_SIZE)
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|c| c.collect::<String>())
                    .join("_"));
    out
}
```

I wouldn't blame the slowness entirely on `.collect()`. The chunking iterator may also be slowing it down. Generally, chaining together a number of iterators, then iteratively pulling data through the chain is just not going to be as efficient as approaches with fewer iterators chained together.

The code above is *roughly* an `O(N)` algorithm *(but a slow one)*, at least judging from visual appearances of the code above without digging into the implementations of the iterators.

I used the [timeit](https://docs.rs/timeit/0.1.2/timeit/index.html) crate to time the performance of each solution. [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/ttappr/ae13d4b8087bf1b0ca38592fc08bd22c) has the code that produced the results below.

- `iterators_yolenoyer` - yolenoyer's iterator approach.
- `procedural_yolenoyer` - yolenoyer's "procedural" function.
- `procedural_yolenoyer_modified` - the previous with some changes.
- `iterators_sebpuetz` - sebpuetz' iterator example.
- `procedural_sebpuetz` - the above using a `for` loop instead of `.for_each()`.
- `iterators_todd` - the example in this answer.

Output:

```
          iterators_yolenoyer benchmark:    701.427605 ns
         procedural_yolenoyer benchmark:     62.651766 ns
procedural_yolenoyer_modified benchmark:     59.283306 ns
           iterators_sebpuetz benchmark:     94.315160 ns
          procedural_sebpuetz benchmark:    121.447247 ns
               iterators_todd benchmark:    606.468828 ns
```

It's interesting to note that using `.for_each()` is faster than a simple `for` loop (compare `iterators_sebpuetz`, which uses `.for_each()` to the same algorithm using a `for` loop instead, `procedural_sebpuetz`). *The `for` loop being slower may not be generally the case for all use cases.*

Comment: Thank you, it's better but the procedural version is still really faster! I guess this is due to the `collect::<String>()` calls

Comment: Replacing the `collect()`s with `fold()` and setting the correct size shouldn't be improving the perfomance much at all. You're still allocating a `String` for each chunk.

Comment: Correct @sebpuetz. It shouldn't improve it, but it actually does to a tiny degree - but it's not at all significant.